# How to detect Audio or Video or Both exist in converted file

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, audio-streaming, video-capture, mencoder

I am trying to convert mp4 or 3gp video files into Flash (flv) format (using Perl script), using following (mencoder) command:

```
mencoder test.mp4 -of lavf -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=flv:vbitrate=1000:mbd=2 -fps 20.80 -ofps 20.80 -oac mp3lame -lameopts abr:br=32 -srate 22050 -o test.flv
```

It works fine, but some files which comes as attachments from mobile phone has problem, the converted FLV file has only audio.

I also used ffmpeg command as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ar 22050 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32K -r 25 -vcodec flv test.flv
```

This ffmpeg command helps to convert to flv, which is failed by `mencoder`.

I am thinking some solution like, need to check whether converted flv has audio and video then will take action depends on it. Could you help me to solve this issue?

**Here is some more info (log):**

[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xb6b9a3a0]multiple edit list entries, a/v desync might occur, patch welcome
** MUXER_LAVF *****************************************************************
REMEMBER: MEncoder's libavformat muxing is presently broken and can generate
INCORRECT files in the presence of B-frames. Moreover, due to bugs MPlayer
will play these INCORRECT files as if nothing were wrong!

---

Unsupported PixelFormat 61
Unsupported PixelFormat 53
Unsupported PixelFormat 81
[flv @ 0xb6b9a3a0]Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[flv @ 0xb6b9a3a0]Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[flv @ 0xb6b9a3a0]pts < dts in stream 0
Error while writing frame.

[flv @ 0xb6b9a3a0]pts < dts in stream 0
Error while writing frame.

[flv @ 0xb6b9a3a0]pts < dts in stream 0
Error while writing frame.

[flv @ 0xb6b9a3a0]pts < dts in stream 0
Error while writing frame.

[flv @ 0xb6b9a3a0]pts < dts in stream 0
Error while writing frame.

Skipping frame!

.........................

Comment: If it works with ffmpeg but not mencoder, then why not just use ffmpeg?

Comment: ffmpeg is not 100% working, it fails to convert some of mp4 files. I need to use both to fix my issue. Quesion: How to detect (using mencoder or ffmpeg) whether audio and video exist in the converted file.

Comment: Please show the complete ffmpeg console output for a command that fails to convert some of the mp4 files.

Answer (score 8):

A possible solution is to:

1. use ffmpeg or ffprobe to analyze the output file,

   ffmpeg -i test.flv

a command line output on a file with A/V stream should looks like:

```
ffmpeg -i test.flv
ffmpeg version N-53818-gfca435f Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jun  4 2013 01:41:53 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-liray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enabibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enablevpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 34.100 / 52. 34.100
libavcodec     55. 15.100 / 55. 15.100
libavformat    55.  8.102 / 55.  8.102
libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
libavfilter     3. 74.101 /  3. 74.101
libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, flv, from 'test.flv':
Metadata:
 starttime       : 0
 totalduration   : 5162
 totaldatarate   : 583
 bytelength      : 376445710
 canseekontime   : true
 sourcedata      : BD075FAE3HH1363450117735644
 purl            :
 pmsg            :
Duration: 01:26:01.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 533 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 640x356, 457 kb/s, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 131 kb/s
```

1. use a regex match to detect if the ffmpeg output contains something like "Stream #.....: Video" AND "Stream #.....: Audio". You can implement and use regular expression in all major shell and languages.

Example:

```
  "^\s+Stream.+Video." and ^\s+Stream.+Audio.
```

Answer (score 3):

this should solve the problem.

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi 2>&1 | grep Audio | awk '{print $0}' | tr -d ,

ffmpeg -i test.avi 2>&1 | grep Video | awk '{print $0}' | tr -d ,
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Great solution, tnx  :)